# How do I remove a span tag in a string with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have this string (which is a string consisting of html tags):

```
const str = "<li class='test'>
    <div class='myDiv' >
    <span class='myClass'>Person is a: </span>
    <a class='myLink' tabindex='0'> Great citizen. Really nice guy</a>
    </div>
    </li>"
```

How would I remove the `<span>` tags along with everything in between them, so the output is the following:

```
const str = "<li class='test'>
    <div class='myDiv' >
    <a class='myLink' tabindex='0'> Great citizen. Really nice guy</a>
    </div>
    </li>"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well I wouldn't do it using regex (since you've tagged that). It's JS, so use DOM functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let str = `<li class='test'>
    <div class='myDiv' >
    <span class='myClass'>Person is a: </span>
    <a class='myLink' tabindex='0'> Great citizen. Really nice guy</a>
    </div>
    </li>`;

const reg = new RegExp("<span(.*?)span>", "gms");
console.log(str.replace(reg, ""));

//if DOM then->
// document.querySelector('.myClass').remove()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use DOM parser for that

```js
const str = `<li class='test'>
        <div class='myDiv' >
        <span class='myClass'>Person is a: </span>
        <a class='myLink' tabindex='0'> Great citizen. Really nice guy</a>
        </div>
        </li>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const parsed = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/html");
parsed.querySelector("span").remove();
console.log(parsed.body.innerHTML);
```